# How to force an applink open in an external browser

Tags: android, react-native, applinks

*Problem facing:*

In the app, there is a link, let's say `https://example.com/campaign` which is an app link. Most of the time we want it to be opened in app. We have set `autoVerify` in `AndroidManifest`'s `intent-filter`. However, there is a requirement that if the campaign is created by a third party, we need to open the link in an external web browser.

*Our code:*

```
const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);
if (supported && isThirtyParty(url)) {
    Linking.openURL(url);
}
```

*What we expect:*

Opening the url in an external browser

*What we have*
It triggered the `Linking` url listener which is calling a deep link handler.

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', deepLinkHandler)
```

It makes sense as we put an autoVerify there. Is there a way to open it in an external browser?